# Help building older version (<= 7.1p2) of OpenSSH Portable (< on Linux or any other Distro)

Tags: linux, compiling, gcc, openssl, openssh

I am working on creating my own PoC of CVE 2016-1907 along with several other OpenSSH involved CVE's for Ethical Hacking / Bug Bounties. Currently,  I have found through Nmap servers running vulnerable versions. I want to create my own PoC so I understand it and they can see the potential impact. I have to use a Virtual Machine either Local or on a Virtual Private Server

I am at the point where This is my current process, but I have many questions surrounding it and i'm hitting a wall.

Edit: This is the error message i'm getting:

```
checking whether getpgrp requires zero arguments... yes
checking OpenSSL header version... not found
configure: error: OpenSSL version header not found.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
/home/cjensen/bin/openssh-build: line 47: DD: command not found
cp: cannot create directory '/etc/ssh.old.': Permission denied
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Here is the latest and greatest script I have
https://gist.github.com/ruevaughn/5b47a62551264de6d1438b1db32982aa

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you receiving any errors? What point in the process is giving you trouble?

Comment: I apologize I missed that critical information. I'll add it right now, thanks I appreciate it

Comment: Okay hopefully I clarified

Answer (score 1):

In line 45 of your script you are passing paths where openssh's configure script should look for zlib and openssl header files:

```
./configure --with-ipv4-default --with-md5-passwords --with-zlib="$tmpdir/$zlib" --with-ssl-dir="$tmpdir/$openhurl)"
```

First of all - you should specify a path to where those files are installed, not where they were build. Also $openhurl variable is not defined in your script. As you seem to build those two libraries without extra options, those paths would be /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/ssl/, so your configure call should be:

```
./configure --with-ipv4-default --with-md5-passwords --with-zlib=/usr/local/include --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl/
```

Secondly, in line 47 you are probalby trying to make a backup of ssh config:

```
cp -rf /etc/ssh /etc/ssh.old.`DD`
```

DD is unknown here.

You are also not checking whether previous step succeded, you should call it as

```
./configure && make && make install
```

as a bare minimum.

Comment: So when `make install` with no --prefix flag on the zlib and openssl libraries - what is the default behavior / where does it put the compiled binaries / libraries by default? How would I go about learning this without say asking it on here?

Comment: Could I store the exit codes from `./configure` and `make` and `make install` and use those for flow control rather than the one liner? like `zlibstatus=`./configure` and then I could gracefully handle the error and control the output so I know in more detail where and why it fialed?